# JSONException: No value for id after completing paypal payment

Tags: android, json, paypal, try-catch

After a user has payed via PayPal on my android app I want the PaymentId to be displayed, with the state and the amount they have just payed. When i'm trying to get the id from the JSONObject it keeps saying "No value for id" when the id in the logcat has a value.

**ID Has A Value As Shown**

[image: Id not null]

[image: Logcat Where it keeps breaking]

When I get to the line `textViewId.setText(jsonObject.getString("id"));` it  jumps to the catch and displayed the error "No value for id". Even though in the logcat there is a value.

Below is my code.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paymentDetails);
//                        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
//                        String status = jsonObject.getString("state");
//                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentDetails.class)
//                                .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
//                                .putExtra("PaymentAmount", totalAmount + commisionAmount));

                        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_payment_successful, null);

                        alertDialog.setTitle("Payment Successful");
                        alertDialog.setView(mView);
                        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                        dialog.show();

                        TextView textViewId = mView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
                        TextView textViewAmount = mView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
                        TextView textViewStatus = mView.findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
                        jsonObject.has("id");

                        textViewId.setText(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        textViewAmount.setText((int) (totalAmount + commisionAmount));
                        textViewStatus.setText(jsonObject.getString("state"));
                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your `id` is inside `response` jsonobject so do

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paymentDetails);
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.optJSONObject("response");// return null or found object
if(jsonObject1 != null){
    String id = jsonObject1.optString("id",""); //return value or empty string
    String status = jsonObject1.optString("state","");
}
```

Comment: Thank you that has fixed my problem

Comment: i am glad that i could help.. happy coding